# IntelliSense: Identifier "XMFLOAT4" is undefined

Tags: c++, c, directx, intellisense, direct3d

```
    #ifndef RENDERER_H
    #define RENDERER_H

    #pragma once

    #include "Font.h"
    #include "Color.h"

    #undef CreateFont

struct Vertex_t {
    XMFLOAT4 xyzrhw;
    D3DCOLOR color;

    enum {
        FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE
    };
};
```

I get this error when i try to compile:

> IntelliSense: identifier "XMFLOAT4" is undefined.

How do I fix this?

Comment: InteliSense is not part of the C standard so obviously this is some kind of an IDE problem.  I suggest you provide additional information about the IDE and your development environment.  If this is MS VS 2010/2012 with DirectX then is your namespace right?

Comment: You may also want to add additional tags as the C tag is quite broad encompassing a variety of development environments that may have no bearing on your problem.

Comment: I'm using VS13 Community. is there anything else you need?

Comment: If it compiles, there is no need to 'fix' anything. IntelliSense isn't reliable. You have to live with it.

Comment: BTW, why are you using Direct3D 9? Direct3D 11 is better supported with VS 2013. See [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from your code where you including `<DirectXMath.h>`, so I assume that's somewhere in Font.h or Color.h.

DirectXMath uses the C++ namespace `DirectX` so you should use:

```
struct Vertex_t {
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 xyzrhw;
    D3DCOLOR color;

    enum {
        FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE
    };
};
```

C++ coding recommendations is to avoid putting `using namespace` statements in a header, only keeping them local to a .cpp file.